# How Do I Use Both Math.max() and Math.min() to bound my dragger

Tags: javascript, math

I'm building a horizontally dragging page layout. There are 3 columns, with two dragging objects. Everything is working fine except setting a max/min value for the drag.

The layout looks like this, with the two dragging bars either side of colB.

```
---------------------------
  colA  |  colB  |  colC
        |        |         
        |        |         
        |        |         
        |        |         
        |        |         
        |        |         
        |        |         
        |        |
```

I need to set it so that colA's dragger's maximum width (which is its left value) is equal to colC's dragger. Likewise, ColC's minimum needs to be colA's draggers' left value.

The function looks like this:

```
function doDragA(e) {
  dragA.style.left = (e.clientX) + 'px';
}

function doDragC(e) {
  dragC.style.left = (e.clientX) + 'px';
}
```

and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function doDragA(e) {
  var posC = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(dragC).left, 10);
  dragA.style.left = (math.max(posC), math.min(0)) e.clientX + 'px';
}

function doDragC(e) {
  var posA = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(dragA).left, 10);
  dragC.style.left = (math.max(0), math.min(posA)) e.clientX + 'px';
}
```

But i'm getting syntax errors. I've console logged the values and they come through, it's just the math max/min syntax I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Why do you use the function names as DOM nodes? `dragA` is a function, how can you get the computed style of that or do `dragA.style.left` ?

Comment: they are inserted DOM nodes. Everything is working else, it's just the math/max/min syntax i'm having trouble with

Comment: In your code `dragA` and `dragC` is clearly the name of the functions, how can they be DOM nodes ?

Comment: It's not really relevant. I'll update the functions to doDragA and doDragC. All I need is the correct math syntax, which is what I'm asking.

Comment: `Math.min(Math.max(0, e.clientX), posC)`

Comment: @Gumbo - just wondering, but can clientX ever be negative ?

Comment: @adeneo No, the minimal value is `0`. So, yeah, you could omit the `Math.max(0, e.clientX)`.

Comment: @Gumbo - Okay, wasn't sure about that, I know it's a little different than pageX/Y, but I never really use clientX.

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks ducde! that works perfectly! well done :)

Comment: how about for the other way around? (colA) do I just invert the syntax so that math max comes first?

Comment: All you need is `Math.min(e.clientX, posA)`, the order doesn't really matter, it just gets the lowest value.

Comment: that doesn't work :( pretty sure u need to set both a min and max

Answer (score 0):

Firstly javascript is case sensitive, and the math object is `Math`, not `math`.

Secondly, the usage of `min` and `max` is to supply a list of arguments, not just one - it returns the answer to 'what is the value of highest/lowest of these?'.

Assuming you want the value of `e.clientX` bounded by some values `valueMax` and `valueMin`:

```
var valueUpToMax = Math.min(valueMax, e.clientX);
var valueAtLeastMin = Math.max(valueMin, e.clientX);

// so we can combine those to bound on both sides:
var boundedValue = Math.max(valueMin, Math.min(valueMax, e.clientX));
```

It seems like they should be the other way around; we limit to a maximum value by using `Math.min`, but it's because we are limiting to a maximum not trying to get a maximally high number.

The general principle is to use functions like in math:

```
c = f(a, b);
e = g(c, d);
-> e = g( f(a, b), d);
```